# How to create a new variable by dividing its observation by its lag?

Tags: r, dplyr, lag

My dataset contains frequencies for each year. Now, I would like to divide each frequency by the frequency of the same variable in the previous year. I created a lag function and got the error message "Can't convert a `quosures` object to function". However, I can't figure out another way of implementation.

Simplified, my dataset can be represented as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

    year <- c(1914, 1915, 1916, 1917)
    a <- c("blue", "green", "green", "blue")
    df_1 <- data.frame(a, year)
    df_1 <- group_by(a, year) %>% count(name = "counts") %>% 
            ungroup(a, year) %>% 
            mutate(y=counts/sum(counts))
```

My code is the following:

```
calc_persistance = function(y){y/lag(y)}
df_1 %>% 
mutate_if(vars(contains("y")), calc_persistance)
```

Comment: Have you tried `df_1 %>% mutate(newVar = y/lag(y))` ?

Comment: Thanks, that worked.